# Data not storing in mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function which returns the domain age of a particular domain. I want to store that value in a database after computing the domain age. I have done everything right as per my knowledge but data is not being sent to the table. My code is below,

```
function domainAge()

{
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fyp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$url=$_POST["urlo"];

require("DomainAge.class.php");
$w=new DomainAge();
echo $w->age($url);
$temp = $w->age($url);

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO results(domain_age) VALUES ($temp)");
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

The name of the table is results and the column name is domain_age. Can you please tell me why the value is not being stored in the DB? the datatype im using is varchar for the domain_age. 
Thank you.

Comment: No luck! Its still NULL in the database! The data is displaying perfectly in my browser, just its not being sent to the database.

Comment: What is the field type of domain_age?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO results(domain_age) VALUES ('".$temp."')");
```

Comment: Please provide output of `var_dump($temp);`

Comment: string(17) "3 years, 129 days"

Comment: Please provide structure of `results` database table - how much length of `domain_age` field? And after your insert you see new record in database table but `domain_age` field is `NULL`?

Comment: data type is varchar, length is 20, "NOT NUll? is unchecked... When i perform the analysis for domain age, i get a new row, stating domain_age field NULL.

Comment: Take this sql query `INSERT INTO results(domain_age) VALUES ('3 years, 129 days')` and run it in `sql client` or via `mysql command line` and look if this query executing successfully.

Comment: Yes! It is running successfully!

Comment: Here's the thing, i dont know if i am doing it right or not but, this function is in a file called functions.php and along with domain age, there are many other functions as well and none of them are being stored in the database! I start a new db connection in every function and end it. Again i start it and end it in a new function. Am i doing it wrong? If so, what should be more appropriate? Thanks

Comment: Add this line of code:
`$query = "INSERT INTO results(domain_age) VALUES ('".$temp."')";` after this line `$temp = $w->age($url);` and use `var_dump($query)` and provide result please